# Why my Cloud Run Instance is using the Default Service account instead of my Dedicated Service Account?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, service-accounts

I have a Cloud Run instance with a Dedicated Service Account (I see it in the UI (GCP Concole) -> Revision/Security tab). I thought this meant, it is set as a main (default) identifier.

In Cloud Run I run a pyton application and I want to generate a signed url

```
credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()
blob = bucket.get_blob(blob_name)
expires = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=86400)
url = blob.generate_signed_url(expiration=expires, credentials=credentials)
```

But I got the following error message (referencing to the default compute engine service account):

```
AttributeError: you need a private key to sign credentials.the credentials you are currently using <class 'google.auth.compute_engine.credentials.Credentials'> just contains a token.
```

My Questions:

- Why the default service account is still the compute engine one and not the Dedicated Service Account?
- How can I set my Dedicated Service Account to be the "default/main" service account of the Cloud Run instnace?

Comment: @guillaume-blaquiere is correct. The key to the problem is **you need a private key to sign credentials**. When you use an attached service account, the service account's private key is not available to applications. To self-create a signed URL requires an RSA private key. The solution is to ask Google Cloud to sign for you via the SignBlob API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a new feature in the python client libraries. You can find [here](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/issues/355) the issue and the solution

Because you haven't the private key with the metadata server on Google Cloud, you can use the Service Account Credential API, and especially the [signBlob](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signBlob) method

Anyway, all is wrapped in the library, use it like that

```
credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()
blob = bucket.get_blob(blob_name)
expires = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=86400)
service_account_email = credentials.service_account_email

# Perform a refresh token with a request to generate a token (Else, it's None)
from google.auth.transport import requests
r = requests.Request()
credentials.refresh(r)

url = blob.generate_signed_url(service_account_email=service_account_email, access_token=credentials.token, method="PUT",expiration=expires)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Although I find it still confusing and bit worring why the default service account is still take into account when the Cloud Run Instance permissions are considered.  Still it sounds me an unexpected behaviour when you register your own service account to replace the default one.